# JavaScript - Sum of Key Values in Object, One Value Gets Doubled

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

[Link to CodeWars problem](https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-office-i-outed/train/javascript)

I need to tally up the scores of all people in the meeting. If their scores are <= 5, return "Get Out Now!" Otherwise, return "Nice Work Champ!"

`meet` is passed in as an object:

```
{
    tim: 0,
    jim: 2,
    randy: 0,
    sandy: 7,
    andy: 0,
    katie: 5,
    laura: 1,
    saajid: 2,
    alex: 3,
    john: 2,
    mr: 0
  }
```

If the person in `meet` is the `boss`, their score gets doubled. (I think this is the problem that I'm having right now - their score is not doubling).

Happiness rating is the total score / number of people in the room.

Here is what I tried and it's passing 76 / 103 tests on CodeWars. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
function outed(meet, boss) {

let values = [];

  for (let i in meet) {

    let score = meet[i];

    if (i === boss) {

        values.push(score * 2);

    }

    values.push(score);

  }

  let sumOfValues = values.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue);
  let happinessRating = (sumOfValues / values.length);

  if (happinessRating <= 5) {
      return "Get Out Now!";
  }
  return "Nice Work Champ!";
}
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you iterating over object and then reducing it, rather than doing the calc in the loop?

Comment: Just trying to avoid confusion - seemed like it would be easier to add the values to the `values` array, then reduce the array later.

Comment: I mean you are already going through every object, so you could just add to the value each time, instead of appending to array (and count the object keys on the way to go for max performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the boss's value to the array twice (once doubled, and once at face value). You just need to add the `else` here:

```
if (i === boss) {
    values.push(score * 2);
}
else {
    values.push(score);
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Since I didn't have the `else`, it was adding the boss's value to the array both ways. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the double pushed value, you increment the array with one too much values. You should better take add the values directly by reducing the keys with a value for the sum and get the average later from it.

```
var keys = Object.keys(meet);

return keys.reduce((sum, key) => s + (key === boss ? 2 : 1) * meet[key], 0) / keys.length;
```